# Import csv into temporary table with Microsoft SQL Server (lack BULK INSERT permission)

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I want to be able to import a `.csv` file into a temporary table in Microsoft SQL Server. I know there is a wizard but this if for scientific research so we don't want click and point steps.

I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
    Column1 data_type,
); 

BULK INSERT #TempTable
FROM 'C:\path\to\your\file.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   
    FIRSTROW = 2 
);
```

I get:

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

Is this a "dangerous" operation? Is there any way for me to do this with scripting without `BULK INSERT`?

Comment: You need to have the server permission ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS or be a member of the fixed server role bulkadmin. Talk to your DBA, or try using oledb.

Comment: The reason that this requires additional permissions is because SQL Server has to access a file system to get the file and that involves OS users/permissions and network routing. As Stu mentioned, you need to ask for that permission to the DBA or code a little program that opens the file and issues inserts or a bulk insert with a library like oledb.

Comment: @EzLo There is also the fact that bulk inserting can bypass FK constraints and triggers.